# Go and `git worktree` command

Tags: git, go, import, git-workflow, git-worktree

I guess this question also relates a little bit to how you work with forks in `Go`, which i don't think there exists a good solution for.

I am maintaining a old version of a product, so i often fix a bug in e.g. branch `v0`, then i want to cherry pick the commit that fixes the bug into my master branch as well of course.

This kind of workflow is much better when you have access to `git worktree` which allows me to have both `master` and `v0` checked out at the same time. My problem now is that my `master branch` worktree would be e.g. checked out at `~/go/src/github.com/<company>/wt1_server` while my `v0 branch` would be checked out at `~/go/src/github.com/company/server`.

Now my problem is that the imports of the `master branch` is effectively importing code from the `v0 branch` because all of the imports is pointing to that repo, instead of being relative.

Have anyone found a pretty fix to this?

EDIT: A tool like https://github.com/rogpeppe/govers can for example update the paths automatically. But that is going to make it impossible make any commits before reverting it back again. A very poor fix :)

EDIT 2: Looks like `Go` modules could be a solution because of it's relative path to the module - i don't think i can have two modules with the same name installed at the same time though. But it could be a okay solution to run a `go install .` when i have to work in some specific worktree

Comment: Why is it checked out in a different path? Just checkout the branch you’re working on at the correct import path.

Comment: That is the whole point, `git worktree` gives you the possibility to work on several branches at the same time, and cherry pick commits between them. 

Aside from the boosted development speed, it also has some performance gains for your IDE to not rewrite your entire file system every time you want to switch between 2 branches.

There is probably some blog post somewhere for additional benefits of the `git worktree` command.

Comment: I understand `worktree`, but you're saying "It doesn't work well when I do it wrong, but I want to continue doing it wrong". With GOPATH either need to checkout the branch at the correct import path, or rewrite the import paths. With modules you can do a local replace, but once you commit modules you're still going to have to fix the `go.mod` each time you switch `worktree`.

Comment: Why are you saying i want to continue doing it the wrong way?  i can't do it at all.

As i read your comment, you're just saying that it cant be done, that is fair enough input - but could be put in a more brief form.

Comment: By "wrong way", I just mean you're fighting against the go tools. Give go modules a try. If you're only working within the same module, you might not have any problems. If you're working between modules then it's still going to be inconvenient to have multiple trees.

Comment: Yeah i will give it a go :) thanks